# My android application keeps force closing

Tags: android

My code it self in eclipse contains no errors, however when I run it on my device it says, "Unfortunately, SMSFree has stopped."

Here is a copy of my log cat:

```
07-04 10:57:11.773: E/AndroidRuntime(17647): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and here is a copy of my source code:

```
package com.johnnydicamillo.freesms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SMSFreeActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button send;
    EditText message, number;
    WebView wv;
    Spinner spinner;
    String[] carriers = { "Sprint", "Verizon", "AT&T", "Boost", "T-Mobile" };
    String carrierAddy;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvGmail);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    try {
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            SMSFreeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            carriers);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        carrierAddy = "@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
        break;
    case 1:
        carrierAddy = "@vtext.com";
        break;
    case 2:
        carrierAddy = "@txt.att.net";
        break;
    case 3:
        carrierAddy = "@myboostmobile.com";
        break;
    case 4:
        carrierAddy = "@tmomail.net";
        break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I am assuming no one is going to steal this code just out of respect. Thanks for your help guys. I am beginning android developer.

Comment: Which line is that being thrown on?

Comment: One advice, use logcat, it will pin point the line of code that has thrown the exception. Using stackoverflow to review your code for NullPointerException without a logcat is a waste of time.

Comment: What @Siddharth has said is 100% correct! This applies to other fly-by-nighters userxxxxx registrations in the hope that *we* are the magic bullet for your problems. May I remind the op and other potential fly-by-nighters to read this [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com), not for us, but for **your** own benefit :) Am not being harsh - this is StackOverflow :)

Comment: Sorry I thought I added the log cat. I am still really new to this program.

Comment: "I am assuming no one is going to steal this code just out of respect." - By posting this here you have agreed to licence it under [(CC BY-SA 3.0)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). So if someone were to use it(within the terms set forth by that licence), it wouldn't be considered "stealing"

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where your define `spinner` in your onCreate(). You need something like

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

before:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: @user1502224 Glad I could help. Please click the checkmark in the upper-left corner of this answer to close out the question.